# Field won't take focus after error

Tags: javascript, html

Probably going to be something really obvious that I can't find again.  But any help, as always, is appreciated.

My javascript error messages and focus settings work fine with all of the validation functions on submit, but I can't get the field to take focus with the onblur validations.  The error message correctly appears but the focus is going to the next field in the form.

Here's my code for the field in question Javascript first:

```
function validatexxxx()
{
var e = document.getElementById('xxxxNumber');
//check to see if the xxxx number is already in use.
for (i = 0; i < xxxxArray.length;i++) {

if (e.value == xxxxArray[i]) {
    alert("That xxxx Number is already in use!");
        e.focus();
        return false;
    }//end if e.value = xxxxarray 

}//end for loop
var eText = e.value;
if (eText.length >= 15) {

    alert("xxxx Number must be less than 15 characters long!");
    e.focus();
    return false;
}
    return true;

}
```

And the html where the input is:

```
<tr><td>xxxx No.: </td><td><input type="textbox" id="xxxxNumber"
name="xxxxNumber" onblur="return validatexxxx();"/> </td> </tr>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Trying to force focus from a "blur" handler is inherently problematic. Try this: wrap you calls to `.focus()` in a timeout handler. That'll let the "blur" event complete before the attempt to set focus:

```
setTimeout(function() { e.focus(); }, 1);
```

Also, `alert()` can be problematic too, especially in Safari. That browser has (or had, in the past; I haven't tried lately) a tendency to imagine that the appearance of the "alert" window means that the main browser window has lost focus. After that, Safari will completely ignore any calls to `.focus()`. Your interface would look better with a custom "dialog" scheme, or some other way of reporting validation errors.

Comment: Thanks Pointy..  That worked for the time being, but I think I'll try to go further and get some custom dialogs in there.  I've implemented them in the past.  This is my first web dev gig out of college, and they really pushed the release date on this mini project.  So I was just trying to get it functional right away

Comment: I certainly want to learn the things the right way though so any other hints or tips you have, let me know.

Answer (score 3):

It's the `alert()` that's causing the focus to go away. After the popup is displayed, you're setting the focus. But as user needs to click `OK` in the appeared popup window, the focus is lost.

Comment: I'm at least 7% sure that `alert()` and `confirm()` are blocking calls.

Comment: @Cobra_Fast they are, but it's true that those low-level windows used by the browser for those routines can definitely confuse things. Also, they're ugly.

Answer (score 0):

Try to put it in a closure like this.

```
e.focus(function() {
   alert("xxxx Number must be less than 15 characters long!");  
});
```

Comment: The `.focus()` method doesn't take any parameters.

Comment: Well yes, but in this case "e" is a raw DOM element, not a jQuery object. Also, calling the jQuery `.focus()` method will establish the event handler, but it will not force the focus to change, which is what the OP wants to do.